# Entity Framework SaveChanges hangs while doing nothing - SQL times out

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

Here's the story. I've got a generic save web service call that uses Entity Framework to save any entity object. The reasons it's done in this way is, one, there's a very tight schedule for this, and two, we're talking to an old version of Windows Mobile, so there's little support for better, more modern ways of doing this. The meat of this is an array of EntityObjects that's passed into the web service, which then:

```
       Using TESTEntity As New TESTEntities(EntityConnectionString)

            For Each change As Object In Changes
                Dim item As EntityObject = DirectCast(change, EntityObject)

                Dim NewState As EntityState
                If (item.EntityKey Is Nothing) Then
                    NewState = EntityState.Added
                Else
                    NewState = EntityState.Modified
                End If

                TESTEntity.AttachTo(change.GetType().Name, item)

                TESTEntity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, NewState)

            Next

            TESTEntity.SaveChanges()



        End Using
```

This function worked fine for a while. It still works fine for us here at development, but it fails strangely at a client. It gets to SaveChanges and then just hangs until a `SQLTimeoutException` is thrown.

First, I've tried turning up the CommandTimeout value without any luck.

Second, this webservice is called numerous times all over the place, but appears to only fail in one specific place, and only on the client site but not here. We don't have easy access to the client site or database, but we've confirmed that the database schema's match and we're fairly certain their mobile software is the most recent version (We're confirming that tonight).

Third, we've run the SQL profiler on the client's SQL Server and see that the only request that's being made is the `Audit Login` without any other queries being run. This `SaveChanges` is only doing a small handful of Inserts and Updates, so it shouldn't be timing out in the first place.

If there was a bad entity object or something about the schema didn't match, I would expect a different exception, or at least the SQL Profiler to show something other than just the Audit Login... I'm at a loss as to what is happening, any thoughts?

Comment: Is another process locking the table in question?

Comment: @GertArnold It's accessing a number of tables, do you know if the SQL Profiler would show some attempt at a query (each query shows a begin and an end) if a table is locked?

Comment: Good question. I think it would show a start of the query, so your observation probably shows that the query is not even executed.

Comment: @GertArnold Your comment did make me poke around more though, and it looks like when Entity does an update it uses sp_executesql, which doesn't give me a start, it only shows an RPC:Completed